# 2 layer switch how to handle the datagram bigger than MTU？

Tags: ethernet, switching, mtu

If the datagram bigger than MTU， 2 layer switch will drop it? Dose 2 layer switch can report a ICMP? If not report ICMP, how can I determine the data size to pass the switch successfully?

Answer (score 0):

> If the datagram bigger than MTU， 2 layer switch will drop it?

Yes. A switch does not forward frames larger than the (configured) maximum size and drops them. For standard Ethernet, that's 1500 bytes payload plus 18 bytes L2 overhead. Note that *MTU* is an L3 term referring to the maximum packet size that an underlying network can transport.

> Does 2 layer switch report a ICMP?

No. A layer-2 switch generally sends no ICMP messages nor is there an ICMP message to report oversized frames in L2.

A layer-3 switch used as gateway should return an ICMP *Fragmentation required* when the destination network's MTU does not admit the IP packet without fragmentation and its *DF* bit is set or IPv6 is used. For IPv4 without *DF*, the gateway just fragments the packet.

> If not report ICMP, how can I determine the data size to pass the switch successfully?

On an unmanaged switch, see above for the maximum standard size. A few support jumbo frames, check their documentation. On some managed switches you can configure the maximum frame size globally or by VLAN. Methods and syntax vary.

Comment: If on an environment I can‘t controll，for example internet,  if a path has a switch with no standard size(for example 720) but I don't know. Assume I use TCP, it will  consult the mss to be 1460. It may loss datagram.  If the 2-layer switch report icmp, I can find the min MTU in path by path mtu searching, but how can I do in this case?

Comment: The MTU is only controllable for L2 segments that are locally attached. *Path MTU* needs to be discovered (hence *path MTU discovery* ([PMTUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery)). PMTUD is mandatory for IPv6 where there's no in-path fragmentation any more, but IPv4 usually fragments along the path.

Comment: “but IPv4 usually fragments along the path”--but you said L2 swith not fragment the packet,just drop them.

Comment: Fragmentation is a network-layer function on packets, it's not possible with frames on the data link layer. With IPv4 a router, a currently routing L3 switch, or the source can fragment a packet, and only when the *DF* bit isn't set. With IPv6, only the source can fragment a packet.

Comment: So, I wanna know how a big IPv4 datagram can pass a L2 switch

Comment: The MTU over standard Ethernet is 1500 bytes as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: If the L2 switch feedback ICMP, I can use   path MTU discovery (PMTUD) to decide the package size. But if not, how can I do

Comment: An L2 switch does not send any ICMP messages, see above. The *Fragmentation required* is supposed to be sent by the L3 hop attached to the segment that doesn't allow the current packet size to be passed.

Comment: Internet seems not completely Ethernet. I have problem that,  I create a TCP link from one country to another country, the mss consult to be 1460, but between the two contries path seems use PPPOE,so the MTU a little less.  If I don't set the DF bit，the package will be dropped.

Comment: The actual state is,  the DF bit is 0,  it should fregment, but in actual fact, it didn't. The package is loss.

Comment: No, the Internet is far from being uniform. If the network isn't under your control, there's nothing much you can do. You should first check for IMCP *Fragmentation required* and if neither that nor an ACK is returned (=packet loss), consider an MTU reduction in the path, requiring MSS reduction. (Note that you seem to be mixing L2, L3 and L4 pretty freely which could cause your confusion.)

Comment: A little clear.  if network neither ICMP Destination Unreachable is returned nor an ACK is returned, I can't use the PMTUD in TCP,  I just can modify the MSS manually. Am I right?

Comment: PMTUD uses ICMP *Fragmentation required* (3-4). Other *Destination unreachable* messages (3-x) don't help, neither does ACK. PMTUD requires OS stack support, so you might be on your own, modifying MSS. Note that PMTUD is mandatory for IPv6 (using ICMPv6 *Packet too big* 2-0), optional for IPv4 but the latter usually just fragments oversized packets in-path.

Comment: ok. I got it. Thanks a lot.